# Ionizing materials

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

My question is pretty simple:

Let's say I have an object composed of tow different substances. Is it possible to only ionize the particles of one of the two materials without also affecting the second material?

Comment: how do you want to ionize your stuff, what kind of substances?

Comment: @trula I don't really undetsand what you mean by "how". What I can imagine is by using electromagnetic radiation. When it comes to materials I'm talking about carbon mainly. I would also like to know if this ionization is also possible on ink-like substances as my experiment is evelved around ink absorbtion. Ink is a much more complicated situation though because it is not made of one substance but a combination of organic and non-organic molecules.

Answer (score 1):

Ionisation is a simple model for gas. There atoms/molecules interact by scattering on each other and individual electrons can be knocked off and the atom becomes ionized.

In solids though special models have to be developed, because there is a lattice organization and it has no meaning to talk of ionization of single atoms. In liquids one can have  conductivity from individual molecule ionizations, [see this for exacmple.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water).

For example a useful model is the [band theory of solids,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) where there are the conduction band electrons shared by the whole lattice, the valence electrons tied up to the atoms. One could say that the atoms are always ionized when a voltage difference exists in a conductor  lattice, because the conduction band electrons instantaneously leave the atoms in the valence band , charged.

It may be that the conduction in a conductor of two types of atoms   depends on only one of them for conduction, still though any ionization is instantaneous, and not measurable except as the current and the voltage difference .

The particular model taking into account bonds etc could fit that the current is due to the electrons from one of the substances, the other being inert.

Comment: The crucial point is that, even considering hypothetical scenario, the question is about two different substances. A thoroughly extended band or treatment should be reserved to a single substance. Say we mix two different metals and each retain a minimum individual domains sizes. Then each one will retain its own ionization energy. I think the system proposed is ill defined and anyway one should move to a complicated analysis. As you said, there is not ionisation energy for solids, strictly. Still, your answer has the merit to point to the complexity of the situation.